# Check if map<string, string> contains another map<string, string>

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a map of strings in c++, and want to check if another map is contained into the first one. For example

```
map<string, string> mA = {{"a", "a1"}, {"b", "b1"}, {"c", "c1"}};
map<string, string> mB = {{"b", "b1"}, {"a", "a1"}};

bool contained = isContained(mB, mA);

// isContained returns true iff every key value pair from mB is contained in mA.
// in this case is true because the pair <"b", "b1"> is contained in mA,
// and the pair <"a", "a1"> is contained too.
```

I would prefer to use some function from the STL, to make my code cleaner.

Note that there is no particular sort in the map.

In java for example, this can be solved easily using

```
h2.entrySet().containsAll(h1.entrySet())
```

But honestly I don't know how to solve it in c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::includes(mA.begin(), mA.end(),
              mB.begin(), mB.end());
```

This only works on sorted containers, which `std::map` is. But it won't work on an `unordered_map`, for example. Also note this does take the mapped value into account. In order to ignore it, and only compare keys, you can pass a custom comparison to `std::includes`.

Comment: Excellent answer!!!!!! . It worked fine! I just realized that doesn't matter the order that are added the keys into a std::map, it is sorted. Thanks